# Issue while executing justify_days() in JasperReports

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports

While I execute the following query in both PostgreSQL and *JasperReports*, then I get the different outputs

Query

```
 select justify_days(cast((select 100)||' month' as interval))
```

Result via *PostgreSQL*:

```
 "8 years 4 mons"
```

Result via *JasperReports*:

```
"8 years 4 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mints 0.00 sec"
```

How can I get the postgres sql result with *JasperReports*?

Comment: I'm curious of your field declaration in the jrxml is it class="org.postgresql.util.PGInterval" or class="java.lang.String"?

Comment: post the jrxml of your field definition and how you use it in the textField

Answer (score 0):

```
$F{justify_days}.getYears() +" years " + $F{justify_days}.getMonths() + " mons"
```

by setting this on your textField you can get your desired result.

Suggestion: when you open textField after double click then click on any field and you can see what all java function you can utilize for that field in next section of current window.